# Android. Форматы экранов.

Tags: android

Вот я делаю каждую картинку для 5 форматов (ldpi,mdpi и тд). При скачивании с гугл плея только одна папка в зависимости от телефона будет использоваться? Или же все остальные папки тоже мертвым грузом будут занимать место на телефоне?

Comment: Мертвым грузом будут занимать место на телефоне.

Comment: Если быть точнее, то apk будет храниться на телефоне. Но при запуске будет распакована только подходящая папка. Для этих целей в Google Play есть возможность делать разные apk для разных устройств. Используя ant/gradle можно настроить автоматическую компиляцию нужных бинарников.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все ваши ресурсы будут лежать на телефоне после скачивания из Google Play. Хотите оптимизировать при первом запуске грузите из Web, определив параметры устройства.